# convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand Error

Tags: c#, umbraco

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I got this error while creating Usercontrol

it is in this code.

```
  protected void gvDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
int Slno = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
var ProductNum = gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ProductNumber"].ToString();
TextBox txtShortDesc = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ShortDesc");
SqlCommand cmd= SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text,"UPDATE sydShortDesc set ShortDesc='"+ txtShortDesc.Text+ " ' WHERE ProductNumber='"+ ProductNum +"'  ");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
lblresult.Text = username + " Details Updated successfully";
gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
BindEmployeeDetails();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well presumably your `SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar` method is declared to return `object`, not `SqlCommand`. Indeed, I wouldn't *expect* it to return `SqlCommand` - I'd expect it to return the results of executing the given query. I suspect you don't want to call `ExecuteScalar` in the first place.

As a *very important* aside, your current code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) - you should use parameterized SQL instead of embedding values directly into the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

From the name of your function `SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar` it appears that this function executes the command and return the result set, **not a new** SqlCommand. That is why you are getting the error.

Couple of other things, You should **always use Parameterized queries** to save yourself from [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)